# How to read PDF file as template using iText

Tags: java, itext7

I'm trying to read a single page PDF file and replace some of it's content dynamically (i.e date, page numbers).

[Here](https://ufile.io/ha5reuy1) is my sample PDF file.
(The file was created with `MS Word`. All elements are tables)

I know I can do this with `Acro Form` but in `Word` it's much simpler for users to create templates.

In this example I want to replace `{CREATE_DATE}` with current date, `{DATA_AREA}` will be the content area and `{PAGE_NUMBER}` with current page number.

What I have done so far is to override `ITextExtractionStrategy` and pass it as `delegate` to `GlyphTextEventListener`.
By doing this I could read every single char, get it position and calculate the total amount of width it takes, then, I pass the results to `IEventHandler` for every new page.

```
private void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {

            if (renderInfo.getText().trim().length() == 0) { 
                if (text.isEmpty()) {   
                    return;
                } else {    

                    LineSegment ascent = renderInfo.getAscentLine();
                    endX = ascent.getEndPoint().get(0);
                    endY = ascent.getEndPoint().get(1);

                    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(initX, initY, endX - initX, endY - initY);

                    FontFilter fontFilter = new FontFilter(rectangle);
                    boolean accept = fontFilter.accept(renderInfo, EventType.RENDER_TEXT);

                    float fontSize;
                    if (accept) {
                        fontSize = fontFilter.getFontSize();
                    }else {
                        fontSize = 8;
                    }


                    SimpleTextWithRectangle textWithRectangle = new SimpleTextWithRectangle(rectangle, text,
                            fontSize);
                    textWithRectangleList.add(textWithRectangle);

                    text = "";
                    initX = 0; initY = 0; endX = 0; endY = 0;
                    return;
                }
            }

            LineSegment descent = renderInfo.getDescentLine();

            if (text.isEmpty()) { // start word
                initX = descent.getStartPoint().get(0);
                initY = descent.getStartPoint().get(1);
            }

            text = text + renderInfo.getText();

        }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the boundaries (lines if possible) so I could define the data area.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **A** *[Here](https://imgur.com/dkPWbGM) is my sample PDF file* - Unless I didn't understand the imgur UI, that's not a PDF but an image. **B** Designing a solution so that one has to replace PDF content is usually a bad idea. Even if *it's much simpler for users to create templates* that way, what's the use if the solution eventually has sporadic issues recognizing and replacing tags?

Comment: A. This is screenshot of a PDF. B. Users will have guidelines to create the template. Thanks.

Comment: *This is screenshot of a PDF.* - Indeed, and as such it cannot serve as a representative example based on which to explain how to *get the boundaries (lines if possible)*.

Comment: I've updated the link now you can download the file. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into this later. Just to give a hint why sharing the PDF was necessary: On first inspection of it I saw that the *lines* you see in the PDF actually are slim *filled rectangles*. If one had thought them to be *stroked lines* and tried to help you based upon that assumption, that help would not have allowed to find any lines at all in your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that provide me the lines.

My solution is to override `RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy`, then implement 
`eventOccurred` like this:

```
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if (data instanceof TextRenderInfo) {
            super.eventOccurred(data, type);

        } else if (type == EventType.RENDER_PATH) {
            readRectangles((PathRenderInfo) data);
        } else if (type == EventType.RENDER_IMAGE) {
            readImage((ImageRenderInfo) data);
        }
    }
```

Now in `readRectangles` I can get all lines from the path and to calculate data area boundaries.